# Eclipse warning

Tags: eclipse, file-io, warnings

I am getting the following warning

```
Null passed for nonnull parameter of new java.util.Scanner(Readable) in     
  model.WordCount.getFile(File).
```

Why am I getting this and how do I get rid of this warning? Here is the method:

```
  /**
   * Receives and parses input file.
   * 
   * @param the_file The file to be processed.
   */
  public void getFile(final File the_file) {
    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
      fr = new FileReader(the_file);
    } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner input = null;
    String word;
    input = new Scanner(fr);
    while (input.hasNext()) {
      word = input.next();
      word = word.toLowerCase().
          replaceAll("\\.|\\!|\\,|\\'|\\\"|\\?|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\*|\\$|\\#|\\&|\\~|\\;|\\:", "");
      my_first.add(word);
      setCounter(getCounter() + 1);
    }
    input.close();
  }
```

I had to initialize the `FileReader` to null to avoid an error. This is what triggered the warning though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line

```
fr = new FileReader(the_file);
```

throws an exception, then `fr` remains null and will definitely not work in the Scanner. That's what the warning is about.

It's basically telling you that printing the stack trace of an exception is no proper error handling. Instead you should think about returning out of the method in case of that early exception. Or alternatively, you may want to put the exception handling block around all code of the method, not just around that single line. Then the warning will also vanish, as an exception would lead to not executing any further code in the method.